# "Preparing to configure Windows" Stuck

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

After updates, I get stuck at "Preparing to configure Windows Updates." When I shut my PC down by holding down on the power, turn it on into Safe Mode, it says updates failed and it's reverting them. When it's done reverting them, it shuts down again. When I turn it on again, it's back to "Preparing to configure Windows Updates."

How do I fix this loop?

Comment: How long did you initially leave it before considering it "stuck"? [Of course, if it was simply working as expected & you lost patience, you now have a much bigger job. Simplest would be to nuke & pave, then restore your last backup.]

Comment: I left it for about 30 minutes. It's not a slow computer, so I don't expect it should take longer than that.

Comment: Yup - you ran out of patience far too early. Windows is notorious for failing to inform the user how long intensive operations may require to complete. By forcing a reboot before it was done, you've basically pooched the entire operation. You can either try to recover from a Win installer USB [with low chances of success], or far more simply nuke & pave, then restore from last backup. If no backup, look to file recovery software that you can boot from.

Comment: Try this loop again and wait for a longer period of time (say a couple of hours) and see if that resolves the update for you

Comment: I'm happy to report that after unplugging it (after shutting it down), I waited three minutes then plugged it in again and this time let it sit, then it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue with Windows 7 update just now (December 2019).

First it would not boot at all (could not verify signature of winload.exe) which turned out to be a case of Windows 7 updating bootmgr on the wrong device, and booting off old bootmgr couldn't verify signatures. Solved by copying new bootmgr to the correct location.

Then, the "Preparing to Configure Windows Updates" truly took very long. This is a Haswell i5 4x3Ghz system with 16G RAM and Windows itself running off SSD with 80k IOPS. So reasonably fast and normally this screen doesn't take longer than 5-10 seconds to disappear.

This time it took well over 20 minutes. Long enough for me to search the web to end up here, read "patience" comments here, crack open a book and read quite a few pages. HDD LED blinked occasionally. Keyboard stayed responsive (numlock/capslock LEDs went on off when pressing the keys). Mouse pointer was movable. So no sign of "crashed", just stuck doing whatever mysterious things that Windows is wont to do.

So if you are able to get back to the "configuring windows updates" screen, simply waiting might still solve it, assuming nothing else broke.

Good luck!

Comment: Ding ding ding, we have a winner!  I ran into the same issue.  For me, I force re-booted after 5 minutes of "Preparing to configure Windows Updates", and then found this answer and read Reddit on my phone for about 20 minutes while my PC did its business.

Comment: I swear that Microsoft $h*t is retarded. I just spent several hrs overtime restoring work computers from installing this update. It got stuck on `"configuring windows updates 100% complete"` message. Tried restoring it to a restore point only to have it come back to the same screen. Eventually decided to let it sit.... and after over an hour showing that `100% complete` BS it got to the login screen. Wow! The client basically told us to disable Windows updates. And I don't blame him. So whoever finds it, don't do anything just leave your system for a few hours.

Comment: And hopefully it will get to something. (And MSFT needs to get their heads examined.)

Comment: I'm happy to report that after unplugging it (after shutting it down), I waited three minutes then plugged it in again and this time let it sit, then it worked!